# Spring boot Controller not working HTTP Status 500

Tags: spring

i am a beginner of Spring boot. i made the simple crud application but i don't any errors while compiling the project but i couln't see the output in the browswer. i don't know why.

```
    .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)
only display like this couln't see the output in the browswer. i don't know why.

Employee Controller look like this

@Controller
public class employeeController {   
    @Autowired
    private employeeservice service;    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
        List<employee> listemployee = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listemployee", listemployee);
        
        return "index";
    }   
    @RequestMapping("/new")
    public String showNewEmployeePage(Model model) {
        employee emp = new employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee", emp);
        
        return "new_employee";
    }   
Index.html

<tbody>
    <tr th:each="employee : ${listemployee}">
        <td th:text="${employee.id}">Employee ID</td>
        <td th:text="${employee.firstname}">FirstName</td>
        <td th:text="${employee.brand}">LastName</td>

        <td>
            <a th:href="@{'/edit/' + ${employee.id}}">Edit</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a th:href="@{'/delete/' + ${employee.id}}">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code and instructions or data necessary to reproduce the problem. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might also want to refer to [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you find any information in your application's logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with a view engine as Thymeleaf you may start
Spring boot app without any error but It's not mean that there's no exception on your templates. Thymeleaf may throw exceptions when compiling Spring EL when you make a request which return a template that is the reason you are not see anything in the browser, in this time you can see some exception in server's log console.

so double check again your templates are corrected by some hint in the server log.

If you see any exception then update the question to include errors log